# bluetooth profiles in-use on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, powershell, bluetooth

tl;dr how do I list in-use "[bluetooth ***profiles***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles)".

In Windows 10, I would like a listing of Bluetooth ***Profiles*** currently in-use for Bluetooth connected devices. Is there a Powershell command or application for this?

For example, which profile ([and codec](https://habr.com/en/post/456182/)) is my bluetooth-connected headset currently using?

Comment: I know of nirsoft's [BluetoothView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluetooth_viewer.html).  Unfortunately the latest version 1.66 does not list Bluetooth Profiles used.

Comment: Have you tried something like this to see what it returns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64888963/how-to-list-bluetooth-devices-near-me-using-powershell

Comment: Thanks @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle . I added a "partial answer" derived from the linked question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partial answer that will list the *Service* of active bluetooth devices; use cmdlet [`Get-PnpDevice`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pnpdevice/get-pnpdevice?view=windowsserver2022-ps) and filter `"Bluetooth"` devices.

```
Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.Class -eq "Bluetooth"}
```

Using `Format-Table` to filter properties, the interesting properties were:

```
PS> Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.Class -eq "Bluetooth"} | `
Format-Table -Property Name,Present,Status,Service,Description,Caption -Wrap -AutoSize | out-string -width 9999
```

Here is a sampling of the output I get

```
Name                                   Present Status Service                            Description                                Caption
----                                   ------- ------ -------                            -----------                                -------
Personal Area Network NAP Service         True OK                                        Personal Area Network NAP Service          Personal Area Network NAP Service
BT-850ANC Avrcp Transport                 True OK     Microsoft_Bluetooth_AvrcpTransport Microsoft Bluetooth Avrcp Transport Driver BT-850ANC Avrcp Transport
BT-850ANC                                 True OK                                        Bluetooth Device                           BT-850ANC
HEADSET123                                True OK                                        Bluetooth Device                           HEADSET123
HEADSET123 Avrcp Transport                True OK     Microsoft_Bluetooth_AvrcpTransport Microsoft Bluetooth Avrcp Transport Driver HEADSET123 Avrcp Transport
Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI)    True OK     RFCOMM                             Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI)     Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI)
Realtek Bluetooth 5.1 Adapter             True OK     BTHUSB                             Realtek Bluetooth 5.1 Adapter              Realtek Bluetooth 5.1 Adapter
Object Push Service                       True OK                                        Object Push Service                        Object Push Service
...
```

Both `BT-850ANC` and `HEADSET123` are headsets. But `HEADSET123` is off. Whereas `BT-850ANC` is connected and active.

Unfortunately, this does not cleanly list [formal Bluetooth profiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles). Also, it's not clear which devices are currently active and connected.
However, it is a starting point.

Thanks to [@Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style](https://superuser.com/users/510662/vomit-it-chunky-mess-style) suggesting this related (but not the same) question [*How to list bluetooth devices near me using PowerShell*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64888963).

Comment: related: How to know if a bluetooth device is connected or disconnected by Powershell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71607722/how-to-know-if-a-bluetooth-device-is-connected-or-disconnected-by-powershell